# Macro for exchange

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server

We've written a macro for outlook to order email address in the To and CC fields in alphabetical order, this is to remove "preferences" from the list. Problem is this obviously doesn't work when emails are sent from smartphones or tablets, we would like to implement this macro or something else into exchange so that all emails passing through exchange have the addresses re-ordered. Does anyone know if it's possible and how to go at it?
Thank you,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is looking into this, the right way arround it is to develop a transport agent (exchange 2007 onwards if not mistaken) with theese libraries:

Here is the MSDN for exchange 2013 (the version i'm using): 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877026(v=exchg.150).aspx

Do not try with microsofts EWS because it won't let you actually get all the flow of emails and edit them, it allows you to access create and modify elements (emails,appointments, tasks) but for individual accounts.